# Load User Profile value set to True in IIS doesn't not load the site

Tags: windows, iis

When I set LOAD USER PROFILE = TRUE in IIS, it doesn't check for the ssl certificate and hence it doesn't load the website.

But the same site loads when I login to the IIS server and run with the localhost. And also it loads outside the server. I have gone through the suggestions but couldn't find the relevant answer.

Please provide any solution

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Loading User Profile` specifies whether IIS loads the user profile for an application pool identity. When set to True, IIS loads the user profile for the application pool identity. Set to False when you require IIS 6.0 behavior.
this basically has none business with IIS certificate authentication.
http://fetchmytip.blogspot.com/2016/10/what-is-load-user-profile-in-iis-85.html
If we want to authenticate the client with a certificate and check the SSL certificate whether it meets certain criteria. we should configure the below feature.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configuring-one-to-one-client-certificate-mappings
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/configuring-many-to-one-client-certificate-mappings-for-iis-7-7/ba-p/346732
To prompt the client to provide a certificate, we could select Accept/Require a client certificate.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831709(v=ws.11)
On my side, when I disable all other authentication modes and require a certificate in the above menu, the IIS always prompts the client to provide a certificate.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.